# Keras convolutional autoencoder, MSE works on fashion_mnist but it doesn't on mnist

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I'm following this tutorial https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html specifically the convolutional example. I don't understand why if I change the loss function from binary_crossentropy to MSE it only works on fashion_mnist.

Using mnist, the loss drops after the first epoch and no longer varies. After the training, the predicted images on the test set are just black images. Using fashion_mnist it works perfectly.

```
import keras
from keras import layers
import keras.backend as K

input_img = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = keras.Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse') # binary_crossentropy
```

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
import numpy as np

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data() # fashion_mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))

history = autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

Comment: `MSE` doesn't punish misclassifications enough but is the right loss for *regression*. For *classification* `cross-entropy` tends to be more suitable than `MSE`. Coming to your issue, i am not seeing any black images when i tried to predict. Can you try and share your attempt in Google Colab, so that we can try to help you the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to perform some Image denoising/reconstruction using an Autoencoder. For this kind of Task, MSE is the right Loss to use. For this task, **you have to use a linear activation function at the output layer**, so you can compare your reconstructed output Image array elements(pixels) with the pixels of the Label Image. Pixels are usually not normalized and have commonly values between 0 and 255.
Sigmoid activation function will normalize the values of your output to values between 0 and 1, which is best suited for classification Tasks, because it gives you the class probability of 2 classes (softmax for more classes).
This activation function is used then together with Cross-Entropy function for classification task.

Answer (score -1):

I got similar issues.

This is my architecture (same as yours + data preprocessing is the same but I am not submitting it here), yellow one are the one I was playing with:

[image]

But I got loss and validation loss like this:

[image]

And reconstructed result all black images as you also described.

Solutions for me were:

1. reduce learning rate if you use Adam optimizer (default is 0.001, I changed to 0.00005), otherwise my loss function got stuck at the same value as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966393/is-it-good-learning-rate-for-adam-method)
   green chart.

And this is the result after reducing learning rate

[image]

2. Change optimizer - SGD helped as well (even with default values):

[image]

3. As suggested above, changing last activation function from sigmoid to linear on 0-1 scaled data also worked for me (as I understood from the code, you also have all in 0-1 interval scaled)

Comment: Please never use screenshots for code. Always paste it as text with proper formatting.